# Put check mark in pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext

I am using the iText (java library) to generate a PDF file.
Here I have a paragraph in which I have to put a check mark

```
PdfPCell cell95 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph((new Chunk('\u2713', FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0,0,0))))));
```

I am using this but it is not working.

Comment: What is the result? Wrong character? Nothing at all? An exception is thrown?

Comment: Is the unicode character existing in the font you use?

Comment: yes the character exists .. i am using /u2713  which is a unicode for check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a unicode directly into a PDFPCell.

Instead, create image of checkmark and insert it into PDFPCell.

Comment: Why not? Lots of PDFs are full of unicode. Can you provide backing documentation?

Comment: While this answer is accepted, it is incorrect, you merely have to use a font properly prepared for the job.

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014211/itext-arabic-font-coming-as-question-marks) and [this item from itext-questions](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg55952.html) indicate that you need to create the font using the unicode character set instead of the default Windows CP1252 Character Set - try using the overload of `getFont` with the encoding specifier:

```
FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 11, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    String FONT = "C:/dev/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.33/ttf/DejaVuSans.ttf";
    FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
    BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    selector.addFont(FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12));
    selector.addFont(new Font(base, 12));
    Phrase ph = selector.process(text);
    document.add(new Paragraph(ph));
```

Here, the point is 1)set BaseFont.IDENTITY_H; 2) only some font provide "check mark"

Answer (score 0):

try this solved.
Download the dejavu-sans  from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans. and keep it in local.

use the below code to write tick symbol into PDF doc.

```
    private static void writeUsingIText() {


    Document document = new Document();

    try {

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_NAME)));

        //open
        document.open();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add("This is my paragraph 1");
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        document.add(p);

        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.add("This is my paragraph 2"); //no alignment

        document.add(p2);

        Font f = new Font();
        f.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        f.setSize(8);

        document.add(new Paragraph("This is my paragraph 3", f));

        document.add(new Paragraph("This is my tick mark ", f));


        String FONT = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Documents\\DejaVuSans.ttf";
        FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
        BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        selector.addFont(FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12));
        selector.addFont(new Font(base, 12));
        char tickSymbol=10003;
        String text = String.valueOf(tickSymbol);
        Phrase ph = selector.process(text);
        document.add(new Paragraph(ph));




        //close
        document.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```